# Pi-mote sockets not picking up signal from RPi

Tags: radio, pi-b+

I bought a [Pi-mote control kit](https://energenie4u.co.uk/index.php/catalogue/product/ENER002-2PI) which is a radio transmitter control add on board and mains electricity socket switched by their own radio receivers.

However I can't the sockets to pick up the signal from the Pi. When you reset the sockets they flash slowly and await a signal from the controller board such as 'turn on socket 1' and then the socket learns that it is 'socket 1' and stops flashing. But it just keeps flashing.

I've tried having the RPi right next to the socket, so I don't think range or interference can be the issue.

I'm using the software from energenie on up-to-date, stock raspbian on my RPi1B+.

I'm not sure how to go about troubleshooting this? How would I know whether the Pi-mote board was behaving? Is there a way to test in software?

Here's how the Pi-mote is connected to the RPi.

[image: photo showing RPi connected with Pi-mote]

Comment: Aare you working with one socket at a time or do you have both plugged in? If they are both plugged in unplug one and try repeating the learning process.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But I am working with just one socket.

Answer (score 1):

**It was a duff transmitter board**.

Energenie were very good, send a replacement out right away after I phoned them. This one works as expected.

(administrators of this site: feel free to delete this question if you think it's not valuable. I thought it might still be valuable to record this answer, even though it's a bit simple.)